# How to make IF statements in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I' like to make a cell show just the letter "A" if A2 > B2 or "B" if that's not the case.

However I get **#ERROR** in the resulting cell when I try to type:
`=IF(A2>B2,"A","B")`

same error if I try
`=IF(GT(A2,B2),"A","B")`

I've made a document to demonstrate this
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KO4V6eqRVnrKgN0ViDBD_etd3WX4CoGZ308MIGO359s/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=IF(A2>B2; "A"; "B")
```

in some regions comma is used, so formula `=IF(A2>B2,"A","B")` works fine if you go to file > settings and change regional settings to "US"

Answer (score 1):

Just simply copy this **=IF(A2>B2,"A","B")** into your cell without any space.
i found some blank spaces in your code

Comment: That was my initial thought too, it seems though that removing some blanks did not fix it. Blanks seems to be allowed. The problem in my case was the regional setting